# Vowel variation of [ɒ]

Tags: pronunciation

Good evening.

I heard in my English book the word holiday, which is usually noted /'hɒlɪdeɪ/ pronounced ['hɔ̝lɪdeɪ]. Is it frequent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that it was pronounced with the vowel of *holy* instead of the vowel of *hall*? If so, then — no, that is not frequent. None of the following lists it:

- http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/holiday
- http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/holiday
- http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/holiday
- http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/holiday

That said, I think the pronunciation could work in a religious context, as a sort of compromise between *holiday* and *holy day*. (Among Jews, for example, [the Yamim Noraim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Holy_Days) are sometimes called "the High Holidays", sometimes "the High Holy Days". Why not split the difference?)

Comment: I wrote it quit precisely, so the vowel is more or less the same as in hall, but shorter. But this explanation is rather convincing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this pronunciation is for the original meaning of the word as 'holy day', or religious day. It is uncommon, but could be used to emphasize the words origins.